# IP addresses to block to stop WP auto-update?

Tags: wp-config, automatic-updates, ip, docker

I am trying to run Wordpress 4.7.0 inside a docker container but the auto-update pushes me to 4.7.3. Now, I am aware that to stop auto updates I'd need to append the wp-config.php file in the back-end, but to do that, i'd need to mount the container and the directory where wp-config.php resides, but I am not completely sure how or if it's even possible.

I figured another way would be to figure out the IP's that WP talks to for updates, and block it with iptables on the VM to avoid auto-update.

What're the IP's to block to stop WP from auto-updating?

Comment: Please accept the answer in case it worked for you..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to block the IP address at all.

Append this code in `wp-config.php` of your website in case you have access to it::

`define('WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false);`

**Alternative Method**
This will hide update messages for all kind of users::

Add this function to your `functions.php`

```
function hide_update_notice_to_all_but_admin_users()
{
    if (current_user_can('read')) {
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_update_notice_to_all_but_admin_users', 1);
```

Comment: I have no access to wp-config.php because it's inside a docker container

Comment: @heisenberg Please recall the updated answer..

Comment: @heisenberg Please click on the tick mark under the up-vote button, if you accepted as your answer.

Comment: Did not solve my problem, sorry. I can't mount from container to host, only vise-versa. How can I access functions.php or wp-config.php on a wordpress install inside a docker container?

Comment: Do you have the access to `wp-admin`??